# One physical device -> two character devices

Tags: c, linux, embedded, hardware

I have a some gpio-device.
I have a some kernel module for working with this device.

```
//headers
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
...

//declarations 
static si_t *gpio_sih;
static int gpio_major;
static struct class *gpiodev_class = NULL;

//some functions for open, read, write, etc
...

static struct file_operations gpio_fops = {...} // <- look up 

static int __init
gpio_init(void)
{
    if (!(gpio_sih = si_kattach(SI_OSH)))
        return -ENODEV;
    if ((gpio_major = register_chrdev(0, "gpio", &gpio_fops)) < 0)
        return gpio_major;
    gpiodev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "gpio");
    if (IS_ERR(gpiodev_class)) {
        printk("Error creating gpio class\n");
        return -1;
    }
    class_device_create(gpiodev_class, NULL, MKDEV(gpio_major, 0), NULL, "gpio");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit
gpio_exit(void)
{
    if (gpiodev_class != NULL) {
        class_device_destroy(gpiodev_class, MKDEV(gpio_major, 0));
        class_destroy(gpiodev_class);
    }
    gpiodev_class = NULL;
    if (gpio_major >= 0)
        unregister_chrdev(gpio_major, "gpio");
    si_detach(gpio_sih);
}

module_init(gpio_init);
module_exit(gpio_exit);
```

I need an another kernel module for working with this physical device in addition, but it must be an another character device in system with an another file operations. What should I do? Write a module by analogy?

```
//headers
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
...

//declarations 
static si_t *another_gpio_sih;
static int another_gpio_major;
static struct class *another_gpiodev_class = NULL;

//some functions for another_open, another_read, another_write, another_etc
...

static struct file_operations another_gpio_fops = {...} // <- look up 

static int __init
another_gpio_init(void)
{
    if (!(another_gpio_sih = si_kattach(SI_OSH)))
        return -ENODEV;
    if ((another_gpio_major = register_chrdev(0, "another_gpio", &another_gpio_fops)) < 0)
        return gpio_major;
    another_gpiodev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "another_gpio");
    if (IS_ERR(another_gpiodev_class)) {
        printk("Error creating gpio class\n");
        return -1;
    }
    class_device_create(another_gpiodev_class, NULL, MKDEV(another_gpio_major, 0), NULL, "another_gpio");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit
another_gpio_exit(void)
{
    if (another_gpiodev_class != NULL) {
        class_device_destroy(another_gpiodev_class, MKDEV(another_gpio_major, 0));
        class_destroy(another_gpiodev_class);
    }
    another_gpiodev_class = NULL;
    if (another_gpio_major >= 0)
        unregister_chrdev(another_gpio_major, "another_gpio");
    si_detach(another_gpio_sih);
}

module_init(another_gpio_init);
module_exit(another_gpio_exit);
```

Or using export global variables?

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(gpio_sih);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(gpiodev_class);
```

and

```
extern static si_t *another_gpio_sih;
extern static struct class *another_gpiodev_class;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all why need all that devices? Why not use standard kernel interface:
/sys/class/gpio?

it allow from userspace read,write and wait change of gpio.

Second. If you have two character devices with almost the same functionality, why not handle them in one driver,
set them one major number and two different minor numbers, properly implemnt open analog from file_operation and all will be fine.

Comment: /sys/class/gpio is created in the first module, if I understand correctly. This is a driver from the developers.

My task is to write additional functionality for the processing of values gpio-ports in a _single_ module. This is a requirement. 

To operate the device in another module I must to export all needed handlers or create new, isn't it? 

If you shift your suggestion to my problem then I have to do the export and create a device with a different minor number. Is it right?

Comment: There are some misundertooding between us. 1)To work via /sys/class/gpio you just need call gpiochip_add. According to your code you do not it. So you invent some bicycle to cooperate with user space instead of standard way.

Comment: 2)You export character device, normaly this used to help user space program to process some stuff (in your case gpio values). This is not expected that you use character device as method to cooperate between modules. If we talk about gpio, then normal way to share this stuff is gpiochip_add in one driver and gpio_request_one, gpio_get_value, gpio_set_value and so on. I thought when you say about another character device, that you want export more gpios from the same device.